# Passport-auth0 access accessToken

Tags: express, passport.js, auth0

Since sometime I am using auth0 with express. But now I have one question. 
This is how my code looks like:

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');

var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
    domain: '',
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: '/loginapi/callback'
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
    return done(null, profile);
});

passport.use(strategy);

// This is not a best practice, but we want to keep things simple for now
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

module.exports = strategy;
```

But how can I access the accessToken in a express request like the user element. I really don't know how, but I already tried some things.

Nils

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it guys!

```js
var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
    domain: '',
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: '/loginapi/callback'
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
    var info = {
        "profile": profile,
        "accessToken": accessToken,
        "refreshToken": refreshToken,
        "extraParams": extraParams
    };
    return done(null, info);
});
```

Now I can simply access the accessToken with the req.user object.